# store the value of cout

Tags: c++, for-loop, cout

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int value
cout << "Input your number: " << endl;
cin >> value;
string s = to_string(value);
const int count = s.length();
int position = count;
for (int i = 1; i < count + 1; i++)
{
    int pwr = pow(10, position - 1);
    cout << ((value / pwr) + position) % 10;
    position--;
    value = value % pwr;
}
```

Instead of cout, how can i store the value of`((value / pwr) + position) % 10` into a variable using the for loop. Thank you very much for the help.

[edit]
I added an array instead

```
int val[7];
int position = count;
for (int i = 1; i < count + 1; i++)
{
    int pwr = pow(10, position - 1);
    val[i-1] = ((value / pwr) + position) % 10;
    position--;
    value = value % pwr;
}
cout << "Encoded value is: ";
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    cout << val[i];
}
```

It was able to output the values I want, but there is a Run-Time Failure #2 - stack around the variable 'val' was corrupted. Why is that?

Comment: just create a vector and push back your results

Comment: Can't use codes we haven't learn in class

Comment: @ Wing Hang Khoo .   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: `How to store the value of xx into a variable using the for loop`? I think you should drop c++ and take jQuery. It comes with built-in for that stores values into variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an STL container like vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  int value;
  cout << "Input your number: " << endl;
  cin >> value;
  string s = to_string(value);
  const int count = s.length();
  int position = count;

  vector<int> outputs;

  for (int i = 1; i < count + 1; i++)
  {
    int pwr = pow(10, position - 1);
    outputs.push_back(((value / pwr) + position) % 10);
    cout << outputs.back();

    position--;
    value = value % pwr;
  }

  cout << endl;

  // iterate through the vector later
  for (auto i : outputs)
  {
    cout << i;
  }

  cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but can't use codes we haven't learn in class.

Answer (score 0):

Store to vector and then print it

Its not so difficult .As you don't  know what will be the size or how many  numbers of result will be there it is useful to use vector .

Reference is here  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int value;
    vector<int> results;
    cout << "Input your number: " << endl;
    cin >> value;
    string s = to_string(value);
    const int count = s.length();
    int position = count;
    for (int i = 1; i < count + 1; i++)
    {
        int pwr = pow(10, position - 1);
        auto val = ((value / pwr) + position) % 10;
        results.push_back(val);
        position--;
        value = value % pwr;
    }
    copy(results.begin(),results.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));

}
```

Output

```
Input your number: 
12
3 3 Program ended with exit code: 0
```